# why django post method doesn't work this case?

Tags: django

html file

```
<form action="/input" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
   <input type="text" name="data" />
   <input type="submit" value="post" />
</form>
```

view.py

```
def a(request):
   x=request.POST['data']
   html='<h1> {} </h2>'.format(x)
   return HttpResponse(html)
```

it shows Server Error (500).
after changing method to "GET" i could use data by "x=request.GET['data']".
but i want to use "POST" method. what should i do?

Comment: have you tried `print(request.POST)` before accessing the data to see the contents that are sent? or changing to `x = request.POST.get('data', '')` ?

Comment: and we would need more details about your Server Error (500). could you check the logs about the complete error stacktrace?

Comment: "print(request.POST)" shows "<QueryDict: {}>" and log file is saying that MultiValueDictKeyError ocurred and when i use "POST.get()" html shows "NONE"

Comment: Your `request.POST` is empty (the `MultiValueDictKeyError` says the same thing); meaning that your data is not being sent in the request. Are you sure that your HTML form looks exactly as you posted in the question? Does the `input` HTML tag have any value when you submit the form?

Comment: when i use 'get' on html and py file it goes right. i even checked packet so i know that browser send 'post' data.